# Xamarin Android Translate Animation Gets Stuck

Tags: android, animation, xamarin, xamarin.android, translate-animation

I am trying to animate an `ImageView` on my Splash Screen in a Xamarin.Android project. The image fades/translates in accordingly, sits in the middle of the screen for a second, and then attempts to translate out. The issue is that half the time the animation gets stuck when translating out through the top of the screen.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
      android:background="@null"
      android:src="@drawable/logo_light"
      android:scaleType="centerInside"
      android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the SplashActivity:

```
public override void OnWindowFocusChanged(bool hasFocus)
{
    if (hasFocus)
        StartAnimations();
}

    private void StartAnimations()
    {
        imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(MySolution.Droid.Resource.Id.logoImageView);
        imageView.Visibility = 0;

        // Fade In
        var fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadeIn.Duration = 500;
        fadeIn.Interpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator();

        var transLateIn = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -200, 0);
        transLateIn.Duration = 750;
        transLateIn.Interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        var delay = new AlphaAnimation(1, 1);
        delay.StartOffset = 750;
        delay.Duration = 1000;

        var transLateOut = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -5000);
        transLateOut.StartOffset = 1750;
        transLateOut.Duration = 750;
        transLateOut.Interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
        transLateOut.FillAfter = false;

        var fadeInSet = new AnimationSet(false);
        fadeInSet.AddAnimation(fadeIn);
        fadeInSet.AddAnimation(transLateIn);
        fadeInSet.AddAnimation(delay);
        fadeInSet.AddAnimation(transLateOut);

        imageView.StartAnimation(fadeInSet);
    }
```

Could anyone shed some light on why this may be happening?

Comment: I would assume it is recreating the bitmap on each draw cycle do to the fact that you are assigning a scale type in the XML and you are seeing an ART GC pause... watch your logcat output for differences during the times that it stutters vs. when it does not.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, but I've done some testing and it is freezing even without a `scaleType` set.